# Shopware 5 to 6 migration with migration tool. Missing media files

Tags: image, migration, shopware, localserver

I am trying to migrate a shopware 5.7.7 shop to version 6. The new shop is on the same server as the old one. The migration creates the products in the database but it does not copy the orders and the image files to the media order of the shop 6.
I have started the migration multiple times with the same result. What did I miss?
I did the steps just like here: https://docs.shopware.com/en/migration-en/Migrationprocess?category=migration-en/shopware5
There was also a message: the media is being downloaded and it was done. But no image-files are there.

Comment: What did you try to far to debug the problem? Did you look at the error log (`var/log/*.log`)

Comment: First there was an out of memory error: Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\OutOfMemoryError: "Error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)"

Comment: I updated the memory limit, started the migration again, error is gone, but the result was the same, there are the products in database, but no images in filesystem

Comment: After the OOM error, did you redo the full process?